# Probability confusing question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I saw this in my probability class past exam papers I saw the answer key but I still can't fully understand. I wish somebody can walk through this with me :)

A company takes out an insurance policy to cover accidents that occur at its manufacturing plant. The probability that one or more accidents will occur during any given month is 3/5. The number of accidents that occur in any given month is independent of the number of accidents that occur in all other months. Calculate the probability that there will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs.

I believe I have to set X to be the number of months in which no occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs?

The answer is 0.29

Comment: What's the probability that there will be *exactly* four? What about five, six, etc.? Then add these up.

Comment: It seems like I can't understand the question thorough enough could you explain a bit? Probably the wording that I can't full grasp

Comment: You can go the other way: find the probability that an accident happens in the first four months, and subtract it from $1$.

Comment: @Ian I think that's the probability that there are at least four months without accidents before the _first_ month in which an accident occurs.

Comment: Oh, now I see: they're being asked the probability that the sequence of trials has 4 0s before it has 4 1s, where the probability of a 1 is 3/5. Sorry, the wording tripped me up, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think at some point in time (maybe when the policy is first taken out), we're supposed to start counting months with accidents and months without accidents, and the question is do we count at least four months without accidents before we have counted four months with accidents.

If there are four or more accident-free months within the first seven months,
then there are three or fewer months with accidents in that period,
so we count four accident-free months 
before we count four months with accidents.
But if there are fewer than four accident-free months 
within the first seven months,
then there are at least four months with accidents in that period,
so we count four months with accidents before
we count four accident-free months.

So, let $X$ be the number of accident-free months in the first seven months;
you want $P(X=4 \lor X=5 \lor X=6 \lor X=7).$
An alternative way to calculate the answer is
$1 - P(X=0 \lor X=1 \lor X=2 \lor X=3).$

Comment: Where is the seven month stretch coming from?

Comment: Yeah I don't quite get it also but it does involve 5th 6th 7th month. But we need to know X>=4 which is 1-P0-P1-P2-P3

Comment: @DilipSarwate The reason for seven months is because it works, as explained in the answer. Consider two sports teams playing a series of matches where the first team to win four matches wins the series. The series may take up to seven matches, but will never be longer than that.

Comment: So this is equivalent to finding nba team winning a playoff series with the probability of winning 3/5 each game?

Comment: Not quite; the probability would be $2/5$ (remember, you want the probability of four months of *no* accidents before four months of one or more accidents).  Otherwise, that's right.

Comment: NHL also works. :-)